# Improve Override / Abstract Method Resolution Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, inheritance, compiler-construction, class-hierarchy

The following chunks of code define how the compiler for my [custom JVM programming language](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil) resolves missing abstract methods and links methods to their supertype methods. The inheritance model is like in Java 8, you can have both abstract and concrete (default) methods in interfaces and abstract classes and concrete methods only in non-abstract classes. Multiple inheritance is obviously only allowed for interfaces:

[`CodeClass.java`](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil/blob/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/ast/classes/CodeClass.java):

```
public class CodeClass extends AbstractClass
{
    // ...
    public void checkTypes(MarkerList markers, IContext context)
    {
        // ...
        if (this.superType != null)
        {
            this.superType.getTheClass().checkMethods(markers, this, this.superType);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.interfaceCount; i++)
        {
            IType type = this.interfaces[i];
            type.getTheClass().checkMethods(markers, this, type);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

[`AbstractClass.java`](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil/blob/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/ast/classes/AbstractClass.java):

```
public class AbstractClass
{
    protected ClassBody body;

    // ...        

    public boolean checkImplements(MarkerList markers, IClass iclass, IMethod candidate, ITypeContext typeContext)
    {
        if (candidate.getTheClass() == this)
        {
            return !candidate.hasModifier(Modifiers.ABSTRACT);
        }

        if (this.body != null && this.body.checkImplements(markers, iclass, candidate, typeContext))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.superType != null)
        {
            if (this.superType.getTheClass().checkImplements(markers, iclass, candidate, this.superType.getConcreteType(typeContext)))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this.interfaceCount; i++)
        {
            IType type = this.interfaces[i];
            if (type.getTheClass().checkImplements(markers, iclass, candidate, type.getConcreteType(typeContext)))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void checkMethods(MarkerList markers, IClass iclass, ITypeContext typeContext)
    {
        if (this.body != null)
        {
            this.body.checkMethods(markers, iclass, typeContext);
        }

        if (this.superType != null)
        {
            this.superType.getTheClass().checkMethods(markers, iclass, this.superType.getConcreteType(typeContext));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.interfaceCount; i++)
        {
            IType type = this.interfaces[i];
            type.getTheClass().checkMethods(markers, iclass, type.getConcreteType(typeContext));
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

[`ClassBody.java`](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil/blob/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/ast/classes/ClassBody.java):

```
public class ClassBody
{
    // ...

    public boolean checkImplements(MarkerList markers, IClass iclass, IMethod candidate, ITypeContext typeContext)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.methodCount; i++)
        {
            if (this.methods[i].checkOverride(markers, iclass, candidate, typeContext))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void checkMethods(MarkerList markers, IClass iclass, ITypeContext typeContext)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.methodCount; i++)
        {
            IMethod candidate = this.methods[i];
            if (iclass.checkImplements(markers, iclass, candidate, typeContext))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (candidate.hasModifier(Modifiers.ABSTRACT) && !iclass.hasModifier(Modifiers.ABSTRACT))
            {
                markers.add(iclass.getPosition(), "class.method.abstract", iclass.getName(), candidate.getName(), this.theClass.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

`method.checkOverride` simply checks if the signature of the candidate and the receiver match, and if the `iclass` parameter and the container class of the method are the same type, the candidate gets added to the list of overriden methods.

This code is all nice and pretty, and also works how I intended it to work, but I fear that it will blow up for a deep class hierarchy with lots of methods (like a collection framework), because the entire process is a strongly recursive operation that requires checking lots and lots of types and iterating through arrays of methods over and over again. Is there a less complex and more performant solution for large class trees, and how do other compilers (e.g. `javac` or `scalac`) solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  However, I've worked on a compiler for a different language that had approximately the same problem.  For each class (type), there was a list of methods _including_ the inherited ones, with some additional information about whether is was inherited, where from, etc.  Then the kind of check I think you're trying to do involves just searching through one array, not going up the type hierarchy recursively.

Comment: So basically, when you declare a class that extends a class or implements an interface, collect all the methods you will need right away.  Maybe that won't work that simply, in case some methods have to be propagated later.  Anyway, I hope this helps, but it's a difficult question to answer accurately.